# JSON diff versioning in NoSQL database

Tags: database, nosql, version

I am creating a system that needs to version JSON documents based on the diffs, similar to what Git does.

When "pulling" data from the server I need to support 2 use cases:

- pulling only changes form certain version upwards (git pull)
- downloading the most recent version of the whole document (git clone)

When "pushing" data to server I also need to support 2 use cases:

- pushing only the changes made locally from certain version number (git push)
- uploading the whole updated document and let the server create the diffs and version properly

I know it is possible to implement this logic on the client side, for example using JSON Patch [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) but i was wondering if there is a NoSQL database supporting this functionality out of the box.
I already checked most popular NoSQL databases (CouchDB, MongoDB, DynamoDB...) and none of them seem to implement this feature.